# Node.js and swig template engine - including template inside template

Tags: node.js, swig-template

I trying to create main page (part of node.js and mongoDB application) that includes login form.
To add view part I included js files with function that returns HTML, but as I can see much better is using template engine. 
Everything is OK until I including one compiled swig part inside another one.
The output of main page is OK, but login part outputs like text on the page.
How is possible to output the login HTML as HTML instead of plain text?

Does more information needed to understand the issue?

Thank you in advance.

```
var swig  = require('swig');
var mainPage_tpl = swig.compileFile(__dirname+'/../views/mainpage_tpl.html');
var formLogin_tpl = swig.compileFile(__dirname+'/../views/login_tpl.html');

var loginOutput =  formLogin_tpl();
var mainPageOutput = mainPage_tpl({
    title: 'Sometitle',
    pagetitle: 'Somepagetitle',
    content: loginOutput
});

exports.get = function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(mainPageOutput);
    res.end();
}
```

mainpage_tpl.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="login_page">
    <h1>{{pagetitle}}</h1>
    <div id="content">{{content}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes.. Please append your mainpage_tpl.html and how you are embedding the *content* variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include literal HTML, you need to tell Swig to not escape it using the [`safe`](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/#safe) filter:

```
...
<div id="content">{{ content|safe }}</div>
...
```

Comment: @Pumych there's a link to the manual below the `safe` word (the link points to http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/#safe)